# Teeth fall out of the lower jaw when I move/rotate the bone

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I downloaded this free shark model (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/great-white-shark-e4f107a6d87b424fb165aba9a53d0665)
and imported it into blender: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x46wm9c2vbnhhal8tbk91/shark.blend?rlkey=5oydr5tzm380xhmuodg9whono&dl=0

 Shark's teeth fall out of the lower jaw when I move/rotate the bone. I checked the weightpaint of the teeth and it doesn't seem to be affected by any other bone.

Can this be fixed?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the teeth seem to correctly follow the jaw, if we select a tooth vertex and check its assignment it looks like it's only part of the *jaw* vertex group:

[image]

The problem is your jaw flesh, it is not only assigned to the *jaw* vertex group but also to *Head* and *Headtop*:

[image]

To fix that remove all this part from these vertex groups (it will probably need a bit of painting so that the transition is smooth though):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!